# How to get the length of all non-nested items in nested arrays?

Tags: javascript

The .length property on an array will return the number of elements in the array. For example, the array below contains 2 elements:

[1, [2, 3]] // 2 elements, number 1 and array [2, 3]
Suppose we instead wanted to know the total number of non-nested items in the nested array. In the above case, [1, [2, 3]] contains 3 non-nested items, 1, 2 and 3.

Examples

```
getLength([1, [2, 3]]) ➞ 3
getLength([1, [2, [3, 4]]]) ➞ 4
getLength([1, [2, [3, [4, [5, 6]]]]]) ➞ 6
```

Comment: based on your examples you are just counting the overall amount of elements in the arrays... based on the title the results for all the functions should be 2,2,2?

Comment: NayeemAhmed - Can you give us an example where @EugenSunic's point above isn't correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use reduce on each array it'll find like this :

```js
function getLength(arr){
  return arr.reduce(function fn(acc, item) {
    if(Array.isArray(item)) return item.reduce(fn);
    return acc + 1;
  }, 0);
}


console.log(getLength([1, [2, 3]]))
console.log(getLength([1, [2, [3, 4]]]))
console.log(getLength([1, [2, [3, [4, [5, 6]]]]]))
```

Answer (score 18):

You can flatten the array using `.flat(Infinity)` and then get the length. Using [`.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) with an argument of `Infinity` will concatenate all the elements from the nested array into the one outer array, allowing you to count the number of elements:

```js
const getLength = arr => arr.flat(Infinity).length;

console.log(getLength([1, [2, 3]])) // ➞ 3
console.log(getLength([1, [2, [3, 4]]])) // ➞ 4
console.log(getLength([1, [2, [3, [4, [5, 6]]]]])) // ➞ 6
```

Comment: is flat(Infinity) "imitating" recursion, brilliant solution anyways?

Comment: @EugenSunic Thanks :). Looking at the spec, it recursively calls [FlattenIntoArray](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-flattenintoarray) while the element is an array and the depth (ie: Infinity > 0), so it essentially allows us to flatten infinitely nested arrays

Answer (score 4):

Recursively count the elements that you don't recurse into:

```
function getLength(a) {
    let count = 0;
    for (const value of a) {
        if (Array.isArray(value)) {
            // Recurse
            count += getLength(value);
        } else {
            // Count
            ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Live Example:

```js
function getLength(a) {
    let count = 0;
    for (const value of a) {
        if (Array.isArray(value)) {
            count += getLength(value);
        } else {
            ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

console.log(getLength([1, [2, 3]]));
console.log(getLength([1, [2, [3, 4]]]));
console.log(getLength([1, [2, [3, [4, [5, 6]]]]]));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just add the lengths for nested array or one.

```js
function getLength(array) {
    let count = 0;
    for (const item of array) count += !Array.isArray(item) || getLength(item);
    return count;
}

console.log(getLength([1, [2, 3]]));
console.log(getLength([1, [2, [3, 4]]]));
console.log(getLength([1, [2, [3, [4, [5, 6]]]]]));
```